# How to make dropdown menu expand to the left instead of to the right of the parent item?

Tags: html, css

Currently, the dropdown is left aligned of the parent item text. This is fine if the menu bar starts on the left side of the screen. However, my menu bar starts on the right side, so text gets cut off the screen. How can I make the dropdown menu align to the right of the parent item and expand left of it?

```
It should drop down like this:

    itemA    itemB
---------
|       |
---------
```

```css
.nav-section {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: 1440px;
}

.nav {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  position: static;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.nav-item {
  padding-left: 4px;
  padding-right: 4px;
  position: static;
  text-align: right;
  width: auto;
}

.button-item {
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
  padding-top: 2rem;
}

.dropdown {
  display: none;
}

.nav-item:hover .dropdown {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  border: solid 1px red;
  padding: 2px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-section">
  <div class="nav">
    <div class="nav-item">
      <button class="button-item">Item A</button>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
          <div class="dropdown-item">Item A1</div>
          <div class="dropdown-item">Item A2</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-item">
      <button class="button-item">Item B</button>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
          <div class="dropdown-item">Item B1</div>
          <div class="dropdown-item">Item B2</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need to do is to add `direction` for the navigation element:

`rtl` for right-to-left

```css
.nav {
  direction:rtl;
}
```

and then reset the direction to left-to-right `ltr` for the children, if the content is in a left to right written language:

```css
.dropdown-menu {
  direction:ltr;
}
```

```css
.nav-section {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: 1440px;
}

.nav {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  position: static;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
  direction:rtl;
}

.nav-item {
  padding-left: 4px;
  padding-right: 4px;
  position: static;
  text-align: right;
  width: auto;
}

.button-item {
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
  padding-top: 2rem;
}

.dropdown {
  display: none;
}

.nav-item:hover .dropdown {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-menu {
    direction:ltr;
  border: solid 1px red;
  padding: 2px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-section">
  <div class="nav">
    <div class="nav-item">
      <button class="button-item">Item A</button>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
          <div class="dropdown-item">Item A1 ...</div>
          <div class="dropdown-item">Item A2 ...</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-item">
      <button class="button-item">Item B</button>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
          <div class="dropdown-item">Item B1 ...</div>
          <div class="dropdown-item">Item B2 ...</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Note that this reverses the order of the top nav items.

Comment: @tobiv I created a div below the parent items so it does not affect them.

Answer (score 0):

```
.nav-item {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  left: -100%;
}
```

If you set the parent with a position: relative; and the dropdown left: -100%, you'll get the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

Use relative positioning on the `nav-item` and the `right` property on the absolutely positioned `dropdown-menu`. In your case, `right: 4px` to take into account the padding on `nav-item`. You might consider using e.g. margins on the buttons instead, then you could just set `right: 0`. You could also use a CSS variable so you don't have to keep track of the values in different places.

(Note: I removed all non-necessary CSS and added `justify-content` on the flex container to align the nav items to the right. Also added `white-space: nowrap` to the dropdown items to prevent line breaks.)

```css
.nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.nav-item {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 4px;
  padding-right: 4px;
}

.button-item {
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
  padding-top: 2rem;
}

.dropdown {
  display: none;
}

.nav-item:hover .dropdown {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
  right: 4px;
  padding: 2px;
  border: solid 1px red;
}

.dropdown-item {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-section">
  <div class="nav">
    <div class="nav-item">
      <button class="button-item">Item A</button>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
          <div class="dropdown-item">Item A1</div>
          <div class="dropdown-item">Item A2</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-item">
      <button class="button-item">Item B</button>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
          <div class="dropdown-item">Item B1</div>
          <div class="dropdown-item">Item B2</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```